# JQuery Fancybox not working after DIV reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net) on my site to open links to other pages (external pages).

Basically the user clicks on a image and this opens a fancybox containing the external page. The image links are contained within a page (the child) that is displayed within a DIV on another page (the parent). The parent has the ability to reload the data in the DIV by reloading the child page with different params that will cause the image and links to change.

This all works perfectly with the first load. But after that when the DIV is reloaded with the child page containing different data, the fancybox popup no longer works. If I then do a F5 refresh on the page, it works again. But only on the first load.

The code on the child page to setup fancybox for the image links:

```
$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".userdetailslink").fancybox({
        'width'             : '80%',
        'height'            : '80%',
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
        'type'              : 'iframe'
    });
});
```

I've also tried the following with the same results:

```
$.noConflict();
$(".userdetailslink").ready(function() {
    $(".userdetailslink").fancybox({
        'width'             : '80%',
        'height'            : '80%',
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
        'type'              : 'iframe'
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the AJAX methods to load the div? You can use the callback function to apply the event handling to the loaded content.

```
 $("div").load("url", function(){
       $(".userdetailslink").fancybox({
    'width'             : '80%',
    'height'            : '80%',
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
    'type'              : 'iframe'
    });

 });
```

This way it runs after the load as well. Of course you do the initial load as you are.

Comment: Thanks, your reply makes perfect sense but I tried it and it's still only loading on the first load. I then just added an alert to the callback function to see if it is called on every load. And it is. But as soon as I add the fancybox call to the callback, even the alert is only displayed once. Weird! Any thoughts?

Comment: Update: I added another alert before the fancybox call. That one gets executed on every load, but the one after the fancybox call only on the first load. Could it be that calling fancybox multiple times for the same element would cause an error? Any ideas on how to unattach fancybox from an element?