# Javascript doesn't execute in Safari when placed in HEAD

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm having a problem with Javascript not executing when placed in the HEAD section of an HTML page in the Safari browser. It works fine in IE, Chrome and Firefox, but with Safari I have to move it down to between the  and  tags.

Anyone know if this is a known issue?

PS. The HTML and Javascript is contained in .PHP files, if that makes a difference.

**Update:**

Code I'm using to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("In HEAD Tag");
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="innerthumbcontainer">
    Test
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I open the page containing this directly it seems to work. But as soon as I load this into a DIV from another page it does not fire in Safari. In all the other browsers it does work though.

Comment: can you add a rough example to your question? that would greatly  help in diagnosing and presenting a solution.

Comment: First thing I'd suggest is to view the source in Safari and make sure your `<script>` is still there (I don't know why it wouldn't be... but I'm not aware of this being a known issue, so that's just the first place I'd start to look)

Comment: I don't know what you try to achieve, but the most secure way of executing javascript after the document is loaded is with document.onready, provided for instance by jQuery.

Comment: @Waxolunist That's exactly what I was trying to do. I actually tried it without jQuery just to make sure it wasn't an issue. Will post the HTML shortly.

Comment: Probably not the cause, but anyway: Your doctype says XHTML but your code isn’t.

Comment: So, you're loading a complete page (doctype, root html tag, head tag, body tag and all) into a div within another page, and that's causing your issue? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would have heard about it if that was a general problem, you probably have a syntax error in your HTML or something, which for some reason makes Safari give up. Post your code, preferably the HTML output, and we'll have a chance of telling you what is wrong.

Edit: As far as I understand you are trying to use a complete HTML page as content for a div, you really can't do that. Depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve you could either use an iframe, or you could cut out the html, header and body tags.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use an entire HTML page as content for a div. I'll try just cutting out the header, body etc. This means I can define all my javascript on the main page and it will be able to access the html objects in the div, correct?

Comment: Thanks! Removing the html, header etc. tags from my div loaded html pages fixed the problem. It also resolved another issue I was having with Fancybox. So double thanks. Could you perhaps post the edit portion on my other question so I can accept it as the answer as well? Link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355566/jquery-fancybox-not-working-after-div-reload

Comment: You should probably answer that yourself. In any case, if you want to get good at dynamic HTML you should cut back on the 3rd part tools, they won't teach you the basics, and you can't rely on them if you want to do more advanced stuff than they were built for.